# Passive Voice vs Passive Voice

Tags: passive-voice

I was studying about passive voice from some good websites but I am really confused with these two sentences.

From grammarbank; Active: People say he **was working** very hard. Passive : He is said to **have been working** very hard.

From grammaring; Active: They reported Vincent **was staying** in Paris at that time. Passive : Vincent was reported to **be staying** in Paris at that time.

My question is about passivization of Past Continuous part. One of them is have been Ving and an other is be Ving. Are both correct? And if it is,  what is the rule.

Comment: You may have it backwards: The passive parts are "is said to" and "was reported to," not the bolded parts. For example, Passive: "It is said that he was working very hard." Bad English, but a correct dated use of passive voice.

Comment: Don't try to study grammar from websites. They're full of nonsense.

Comment: If you wanted a past continuous passive of 'work' (to work can be transitive), it would be:  "People said he was being worked very hard"; and "People said he had been being worked very hard".  Of course, no one in their right mind would use the second of the two.  But it works.  Both, however, are passive.

Comment: In your examples, the subordinate clauses cannot be passivised. Note,  that "People say he was working very hard" is active, but "say" is intransitive.

Answer (score 1):

The Passive rule can ***only*** apply to a **transitive** verb in a **single** clause.
If there are two verbs in a sentence, you can't make the whole sentence passive.
In each of the example sentences, there are two verbs:

- *People **say** he was **working** very hard*
- *They **reported** Vincent was **staying** in Paris at that time*

*Say* and *report* are transitive, so they can be passivized.
*Work* and *stay* are not transitive, so they can't be passivized.

This is why you shouldn't study grammar on the web.